# Do i need Mass effect # installed to import to Mass effect #+1?

Tags: mass-effect-series

I'm planing to uninstall Mass effect 1 once i finished it and play mass effect 2 and maybe 3 in the long run. Can i still import my save from ME1 to ME2 even without ME1 installed?

Comment: Yes. You just need the saves in the correct folders and it'll find them. You don't need to have the earlier games installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [EA help site](http://help.ea.com/en/article/importing-mass-effect-save-games/) is the below step-by-step tutorial. It just imports the savegame from a specific folder, so the game itself does not have to be installed in order to be imported. Just make sure that you don't delete the savegame upon uninstallation, and that the savegame is in the correct folder (just create the desired ones) upon importing.

- Run the Mass Effect 2 configuration utility from the main launcher.
- Click the "Save Games" button.
- Click the "Copy Mass Effect 1 Save Games" button and select the
  appropriate location for your ME1 save game. The default save game
  location is My Documents\BioWare\Mass Effect\Save.
- This will copy the appropriate save games from your Mass Effect 1
  directory into the proper location in the Mass Effect 2 directory.
- Run Mass Effect 2 and, from the main menu, select "New Game".
- Select "Import ME1 Character".
- Your save game should now appear in the list.

  - NOTE: PC players will
    need to choose the .MassEffectSave files they want to import from the
    loading menu.
  - If the above steps do not work, you may have to physically copy ME1
    save games from their ME1 save folder into a secondary ME1 save folder located within the ME2 save folder structure.